# Binding data in a listbox in user control in windows phone

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

```
public class Emp
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

    }

I declared the class like this, but property i didnt set. I set the dependency property for textblock

 public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty
  = DependencyProperty.Register("TextBlock", typeof(string), typeof(WindowsPhoneControl1), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(LabelChanged)));

 public string List
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps not the answer, but there is something fundamentally wrong with your code.

You bind your ListBox's `ItemSource` property to a property `Emp`. Then in the Click handler you add objects of type `Emp` to the `Items` property of the ListBox. This won't work.

In order to make it work with binding, there has to be a property `EmpList` of some enumerable type, preferably [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604). The binding also needs to know the (model) object that defines this property. Therefore you must either set the ListBox's [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) or you specify the [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source) of the binding.

When you add elements to the data-bound ListBox, you don't add them to the `Items`, but instead to the source property of the binding, `EmpList` here.

```
public class Model
{
    private ICollection<Emp> empList = new ObservableCollection<Emp>();

    public ICollection<Emp> EmpList { get { return empList; }}
}
```

Bind like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding EmpList, Source={ an instance of Model }}" ... />
```

Or like below

```
<ListBox Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding EmpList}" ... />
```

and set DataContext, perhaps in code:

```
listBox.DataContext = model; // where model is an instance of class Model

for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)        
{        
    Emp data = new Emp { Id = result[i] };
    model.EmpList.Add(data);
}
```

Comment: No also i got the same result. no items dispalyed in list. what binding path should i have to given to textblock inside the datatemplate

Comment: Binding Path is ok, but `Id` must be a public property. Do you see any binding error messages in Visual Studio Output window?

Comment: Could you please also post the declarations of the `Emp` class and the `EmpList` property?

Comment: i post the declarations above

Comment: Seems like you replaced the previous question text completely. You should keep the old text and add additionally posted content. And i asked for the declaration of the `EmpList` (or whatever it is called) list of `Emp` instances that you bind the ListBox to. But, one other thing is apparently wrong. When you declare a depenedency property `TextBlock` (which is rather confusing, since there is a WPF Control with the same name), you *must* uses the identifier name `TextBlockProperty` for the `DependencyProperty` member. WPF requires this. Also the CLR wrapper *must* be named `TextBlock`.

Comment: And then why is a property of type `string` named `List`?

Comment: the old code deletes automatically when i click save edits.I am in a confusion. So can you please edit your code with the list of 5 strings as you like.I have a major doubt in declaring property.Tel me how to declare the emplist property

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14945/discussion-between-senthil-kumar-and-clemens)

Comment: Then what may be the reason for the blank list. I just write the code as you mentioned

Comment: Sorry, there is nothing to discuss. Maybe you start over and post the question again, with all *relevant* code and XAML, i.e. the bindings and all related proerties.